# observer/subscriber code block not executed in order

Tags: angular

I have the following block of code when calling my service. What I am seeing is that the 'IF-ELSE CODE BLOCK TWO' gets executed before 'IF-ELSE CODE BLOCK ONE'. Why does this happen and what do I need to do to ensure code block one gets executed before the code block two?

```
this.svsOrders.newOrderDetails(customerInfo).subscribe(
      (data:any)=>{           
       //IF-ELSE CODE BLOCK ONE
       if (data == 'Invalid User') {       
        this.isValidUser=false;
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Submit Order',
          message: 'Access Denied',
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Ok',
              role: 'cancel',
              handler: () => {
                console.log('Cancel clicked');

              }
            }],
          enableBackdropDismiss: false
        });
        alert.present();       
      } //close if
      else {   
        this.svsSummary.newOrderInfo(data);       
      } //close else
      },

      error=>this.errorMessage=<any>error
    )   
        //IF-ELSE CODE BLOACK TWO
        if(this.isValidUser){
            console.log('isValidUser value(TRUE)', this.isValidUser)  
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(CategoryPage);
            this.navCtrl.popToRoot;
            this.svsSummary.clearItemList();
            return
        } else { 
          console.log('popping the page now.....')
          this.navCtrl.pop();
        }
```

Thank you for your help.

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code within the subscribe method is not executed until the `this.svsOrders.newOrderDetails(customerInfo)` operation is complete. However, the code *after* the subscribe will execute immediate after the subscription.

So the processing order is:

1. Subscribe to defined observable
2. Block 2 code executed.
3. Subscribed Observable is complete and executed Block 1 code.

To change this, you'd need to move the Block 2 code to *also* be within the Subscribe.

It might be cleaner if you moved both blocks of code into a single method and then called that method from your subscribe().

Something like this:

```
this.svsOrders.newOrderDetails(customerInfo).subscribe(
      (data:any) => this.myMethod(),
      (error) => this.errorMessage=<any>error
)  

myMethod(): void {
 //IF-ELSE CODE BLOCK ONE
       if (data == 'Invalid User') {       
        this.isValidUser=false;
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Submit Order',
          message: 'Access Denied',
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Ok',
              role: 'cancel',
              handler: () => {
                console.log('Cancel clicked');

              }
            }],
          enableBackdropDismiss: false
        });
        alert.present();       
      } //close if
      else {   
        this.svsSummary.newOrderInfo(data);       
      } //close else
      }
        //IF-ELSE CODE BLOACK TWO
        if(this.isValidUser){
            console.log('isValidUser value(TRUE)', this.isValidUser)  
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(CategoryPage);
            this.navCtrl.popToRoot;
            this.svsSummary.clearItemList();
            return
        } else { 
          console.log('popping the page now.....')
          this.navCtrl.pop();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it makes sense. When I try and implement it I get an error: This is my implementaion:

Comment: this.svsOrders.newOrderDetails(customerInfo).subscribe(
      (data:any)=>userValidation(),
      error=>this.errorMessage=<any>error
        )
     userValidation():void{
     
        }

Comment: The error I am getting is that "Cannot find name 'userValidation'." Any idea why that would happen. Thank you.

Comment: You (and I) forgot the *this*!